# awk query for sequential replace a pattern

Tags: awk, search, replace

I found the below awk command to sequentially replace a particular line in a file, but i would like to know how this works.

**Input:-**

```
DS: 1
DS: 1
DS: 1
DS: 1
DS: 1
DS: 1
DS: 1
```

**output:-**

```
DS: 1
DS: 2
DS: 3
DS: 1
DS: 2
DS: 3
DS: 1
DS: 2
DS: 3
```

**Awk Command:-**

```
awk '$1 ~ /DS:/ {$NF=((c++ % count) + 1)} 1' count=3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reasons to believe that the working `awk` command is

```
awk -v count=3 '/DS:/ {$NF=((c++ % count) + 1)} 1' input
```

where `input` is the input file. Also I think there should be 9 lines in the input file instead of 7 to generate the output specified in the question.

Here is how it works.

First, the option `-v count=3` assigns `3` to the **`awk` variable** `count`. If it were written the way it is written as in the question (`count=3` at the end of the command), `3` would be assigned to a **shell variable** and will not be accessible by `awk` and will result in a division by zero error since `count` will be implicitly initialized to `0`.

In

```
/DS:/ {$NF=((c++ % count) + 1)}
```

The `/DS:/` part is the condition for the block in braces. It stands for the regex `DS:`, which can only match the string `DS:`. This condition matches all the lines that contains `DS:`.

For all these lines, the variable `c` is incremented and then taken modulus `count`. Since we have no explicit definition for the `c` variable, it is implicitly initialized to `0` when this code block is first executed.

The result is then added by `1` and assigned to `$NF`. Here, `NF` is the number of fields in the line separated by the field separators. The default field separator (`FS`) is space. Note that space as `FS` is a special case in `awk` and multiple consecutive spaces will be considered as only one field separator.

Since `NF` is the number of fields, `$NF` refers to the last field. In this case, the assignment to `$NF` causes the `1` to be replaced by the value obtained by evaluating `((c++ % count) + 1)`.

The final `1` stands for true condition and the code block after it is omitted. The effect of this is an implicit `print` when the condition is true. Since `1` is always true, the action is always performed and the current line is printed, possibly after the transformation of the last block.

To better understand the process we can track the running of `awk`. `awk` has an implicit loop that loops over lines of the input.

- 1st line: `c` is implicitly assigned `0`. `c++` is still `0` but it
  changes `c` to `1`, `(c++ % count)` is `0` modulo `3` so is `0`,
  `((c++ % count)+1)` is `1`, the assignment changes the last field
  (which also happens to be the last character in this case) to `1`,
  and the final `1` prints this line, so we get `DS: 1`.
- 2nd line: `c` is now `1`. `((c++ % count)+1)` is `2` and changes `c`
  to `2`. The last field is changed to `2` and printed, so we get `DS: 2`.
- 3rd line: Similarly, `((c++ % count)+1)` changes `c` to `3` and
  evaluates to `3`. We get `DS: 3`.
- 4th line: Now here is when the `%` actually takes effect. `(c++
  %count)` is `3` modulo `3` which equals `0`, and `((c++%count)+1)`
  evaluates to `1` again. We get `DS: 1`.

And so forth. This is how it works. Note that if there are any lines without the `DS:` they are printed verbatim.